# golang-migrate command "freezes" during migrations, takes too much time to migrate (10 minutes for 10 rows)

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, golang-migrate, sqlmigrations

when running the migrate on VPS the command freezes. After that I can abort, reboot the VPS, and see that the migration version is one higher, but the DB is dirty. I have no idea how to debug this! The same happens during down migrations.

The command I used and the "freeze frame":

```
ssh -t myusername'@'111.111.11.11' 'migrate -path ~/migrations -database $DSN -verbose down 1 && sudo systemctl restart api'
2024/03/02 16:09:51 Start buffering 7/d add_user_settings
2024/03/02 16:09:51 Read and execute 7/d add_user_settings
```

After migrating down by 1 the version is by 1 lower, but also dirty according to schema_migrations;

How do I debug it, how can I see what goes wrong? Locally everything works well.

Ubuntu Postgres 14, golang-migrate 4.17.0 (installing newest version today did not help)

I tried GPT3, it gave generic answers. Googled a lot, but found nothing.

**UPDATE**,

it finished after 11 minutes on an empty database:

```
    xxx@xxx-Mac-mini xxxxusrnmee % make prodmigdownone
ssh -t 'xxxxxxuser'@'1111.111.11' 'migrate -path ~/migrations -database $DSN -verbose down 1 && sudo systemctl restart api'
2024/03/02 16:09:51 Start buffering 7/d add_user_settings
2024/03/02 16:09:51 Read and execute 7/d add_user_settings
2024/03/02 16:20:58 Finished 7/d add_user_settings (read 4.772845ms, ran 11m7.775711064s)
2024/03/02 16:20:58 Finished after 11m7.783364562s
2024/03/02 16:20:58 Closing source and database
[sudo] password for xxxxxxxuser: 
Connection to 111.111.54.111 closed.
```

**UPDATE 2**

Indeed all I needed is to **wait**. Which makes no sens, since an empty DB with about 5 rows in users table would take 7 minutes to migrate up adding a new column. Locally it is instant (with the same amount of records). Also in the past all migrations have been instant on the same VPS.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this methodically. I'm guessing there is a bottleneck somewhere.

- Monitor resource usage on the VPS while you're performing the migration.
- Forgive my ignorance of golang-migrate, but perhaps test your SSH connection bandwidth. Something like;

```
ssh remote_host cat /dev/zero | pv | cat > /dev/null
```

If you can isolate where the bottleneck is, you can start to look for more answers.

Perhaps log an issue, and see if those closer to the project can provide insight: https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/issues

Good luck!